# Как отсортировать двумерный список?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать функцию, которая сможет сортировать следующий список по возрастанию первого (`list[:,0]`) и третьего (`list[:,2]`) объекта. Как это можно сделать без использования numpy и других библиотек?
Пример:

```
list = [[1.4, [21, 1], 4],
        [1.0, [54, 100], 8],
        [1.4, [34, 1], 2],
        [1.0, [55, 5], 4],
        [1.4, [7, 3], 6],
        [1.0, [10, 44], 1]]
```

Чтобы получилось вот так:

```
list = [[1.0, [10, 44], 1]
        [1.0, [55, 5], 4],
        [1.0, [54, 100], 8],
        [1.4, [34, 1], 2],
        [1.4, [21, 1], 4],
        [1.4, [7, 3], 6]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [3]: sorted(list_, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))
Out[3]:
[[1.0, [10, 44], 1],
 [1.0, [55, 5], 4],
 [1.0, [54, 100], 8],
 [1.4, [34, 1], 2],
 [1.4, [21, 1], 4],
 [1.4, [7, 3], 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно передать в метод сорт ключ, по которому будет сортироваться список. Это может быть лямбда или просто какая-то функция.

```py
list = [[1.4, [21, 1], 4],
        [1.0, [54, 100], 8],
        [1.4, [34, 1], 2],
        [1.0, [55, 5], 4],
        [1.4, [7, 3], 6],
        [1.0, [10, 44], 1]]

list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

После выполнения сортировки, list упорядочится по первому объекту каждого из вложенных списков. Можете написать функцию посложнее, которая в случае равенства первого элемента, будет сортировать по 3 элементу. Но принцип тот же.